# Liferay search results

Tags: search, liferay

I am currently involved in project where we are using Liferay (6.1 GA2).
It seems that Liferay search results provide links to Web Content Fragments instead of to the pages containing them.

Have any of you gone through this issue? Do you know how to solve it?

Thanks a lot pals.

Best, Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a lot more content in the backend than actually displayed on any page. Further, you can display any article on multiple pages at once.

A way to work around this is to specify in the "Web Content Search" portlet that you're only interested in content that is actually published. However, this does not solve your second problem: The content can still be published on many different pages.

Every content can have a "Display Page" - the setup of such a display page is well explained in the UI (see the Web Content Editor) so that you'll actually see a proper page with the search results.

If you actually want to search for pages only instead of content (you might miss out on some metadata), I'd recommend to go with some spider solution that spiders your website, indexes the pages independent of their construction elements (articles) and search that external index.

Comment: Thanks! The approach of using "Display Page" is too complex for our editors. I thought to define different content types which are linked to certain "Display Page" by default. Then there would be always a pair content type - display page. So when new content (with appropriate content type) is added to a page, that page would have same template as the "Display Page".
This looks ok in paper, but it limits the amount of searchable content areas to one.
The other option of using spider-based search would mean that quite good search features of Liferay would be lost (e.g. scoping, etc)

Comment: Note that you can also use the API to automatically set DisplayPages e.g. based on categorization, article type or any other criteria. This would be a probably small customization that will help reduce the complexity drastically if you can specify machine-readable criteria to determine the DisplayPage automatically. You can also have your content go through a workflow and have someone who understands this concept manually fix the DisplayPage if it's not (appropriately) set.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. We decided to go for now with spider solution approach for now.