# Search result: How to show only pages, not different content items?

Tags: liferay

We are using Liferay as a classic CMS meaning that we compose pages using web content articles. There is an issue with Liferay's internal search I could not yet find a proper answer for:

Because web content articles are pretty much only building blocks for pages we don't want the search to show them as distinct items. The user should only get a list of **pages** that contain their search keywords, including all the articles put onto this page.

At the moment we can see two different approaches and both come with certain problems we could not solve yet:

**Idea 1**

We modify the journal indexer and try to obtain all URLs of the pages (how?) where the article has been placed on. Then we add them to the document to be indexed. In the search result we then can access the URLs and collect them. In the end we make sure every URL is only shown once.

**Idea 2**

At some point Liferay renders the entire page before sending it to the browser. If we somehow could put an indexer there, we could index the entire page. We then could limit the search to the special "page documents". Getting the fully rendered page would be the main issue here, because either we would have to run a crawler to frequently trigger this indexing or we would need to find a way to trigger page rendering from within an indexer or something like that.

I have been carrying this problem around for quite a while now and still could not find an idea good enough to spend time trying it out. If anyone of you has some input on those two ideas or maybe an entirely different approach, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: I just found [this answer by Olaf Kock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729666/liferay-search-results) in a another question. If even a Liferay employee is suggesting to use an external tool for full page indexing, it might be worth thinking about taking this route...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just answer myself, because by now we found a suitable solution to solve our problem:

In addition to the default search portlet there is also a "Web Content Search Portlet" shipped with Liferay. It seems to have been part of Liferay for quite a while now, but it's somewhat hard to find, because there is hardly any documentation for it (I only found the [Liferay wiki page](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Web+Content+Search+Portlet), which isn't really anything at all). It searches only within web content articles and shows links to the pages rather than just a link an isolated view of the article. It has much less configuration options than the default search portlet, however. Pretty much all it allows to change is whether articles actually have to be placed on at least one page to show up in the results.

So there is no need for any kind of custom indexer or any other "hack"...all we need to do is use the correct portlet. We will only need to write a hook that changes the appearance of the result page.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is interesting but your ideas are on the wrong direction.

Specially idea 2 it's particulary wrong because you cannot do indexing work meanwhile a page is rendered. Think about performace only.

In Liferay pages and assets are not directly linked: pages have portlets and portlets display assets (web content and more).

Liferay indexing refers and scans assets content, not refers the display result of the assets. Think about permission: the same page can display different contents depends on the user who looks.

bye

Comment: That's why I'm asking...it's a particularly tricky requirement. I just found the table JournalContentSearch in the database, which seems to link journal articles to pages (layoutId). So maybe getting a connection between web content and pages is not as difficult as I initially thought?

Comment: The only way i think to reach you target it's to build a custom search plugin. This plugin does search using indexer and then it filters results to collect pages list. Could be?

Comment: -1: The desire is NOT at all ill-conceived. Displaying out-of-context content can easily damage users' impression of your site. Example: A page with a journal article that refers to a video element. If a user finds the journal article rather than the page, they'll immediately think that something is wrong with the site.

The OP's answer works. Other ways to solve it are to implement a custom search and/or use SEO settings to add "context" to pages.